# why i am getting null ,when try to get last identity value from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table (log table,which has been created as a part of ssis error handling and logging)e in the database.I am inserting a row in this table and trying to get the last identity value from the table using scope_identity() But I am getting **NULL** for the scope_identity?().Please see the dml statement and the scope_identity() statements being used as a part of one stored procedure

```
insert into logging.execution_log
            (ParentLogID, Description, PackageName, PackageGuid, MachineName, ExecutionGuid, LogicalDate, Operator, StartTime, EndTime, Status,FailureTask)
        select @ParentLogID, @Description, @PackageName, cast(@PackageGuid as uniqueidentifier), @MachineName, cast(@ExecutionGuid as uniqueidentifier),
                @logicalDate, @operator, getdate(), null, @status, null



**set @LogID = cast(scope_identity() as int)**
```

but when ever i try to get a value of @logid it returns null only

Please be noted that there is already a identity specification on the column **LogId** of the  of logging.execution_log table

### Regards

***Additional Details(i have just understood when I have done some testings)**
As a part of testing i have inserted some new rows manually like below 
insert into logging.execution_log
            (ParentLogID, Description, PackageName, PackageGuid, MachineName,
             ExecutionGuid, LogicalDate, Operator, StartTime, EndTime, Status,FailureTask)

```
    select 1, 2, 3, **NEWID()**,
     5, **NEWID()**,
            7, 8, getdate(), null, 0, null

select scope_identity()
select * from logging.execution_log
```

then it show the last value of identity.........it is fine
but the problem is when i pass the PackageGuid as **system::Packageid**(ssis system variable) and ExecutionGuid as **system::executioninstanceGUID** then it does insert the row in the table correctly but i can not get the last identity value using scope_identi or @@identity or ident_current(all shows null)*

Comment: `scope_identity()` should be called right after the insert; are you sure there are no other statements in between?

Comment: it just right after the insert there is no other statement in between

Comment: Is `ParentLogID` actually an identity column?

Comment: no parentlogid values is often NULL.At the moment also it has got null in the  table.

Comment: Logid column of the table has been mentioned as identity column

Comment: Do you have an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on the table? If so this will prevent `scope_identity()` from working as the scope of the actual insert that generated the ID is now the trigger.

Comment: You say it's in a stored proc. I assume `@logID` is a parameter to the procedure? Is it marked as `OUTPUT` in both the stored proc and the calling code?

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to cast the scope_identity to an int, even though it's already an int?

Answer (score 1):

Use the output into clause:

```
insert into logging.execution_log
            (ParentLogID, Description, PackageName, PackageGuid, MachineName, ExecutionGuid, LogicalDate, Operator, StartTime, EndTime, Status,FailureTask)
        output LogID into @LogID
        select @ParentLogID, @Description, @PackageName, cast(@PackageGuid as uniqueidentifier), @MachineName, cast(@ExecutionGuid as uniqueidentifier),
                @logicalDate, @operator, getdate(), null, @status, null
```

Comment: +1, I think `values` would be clearer than `select` here, since `select` could in theory insert multiple rows

Comment: Hi David do you mean instead of set @LogID = cast(scope_identity() as int) i need to give  output LogID into @LogID?

Comment: let me tell you evenif it insert multiple records the scope_identity() has to give last identity in the table.But it always give a NULL#

Comment: select * from logging.execution_log 
                                            
select scope_identity()

select @@IDENTITY 

select IDENT_CURRENT('execution_log') 

for all these queries it is giving null(even if there are records in the table and Logid values are also there)

Comment: Please see the table and sample data(As i am new to Stackoverflow,I can not insert picture)

Comment: LogId ParentLogId Description PackageName PackageGuid

--------------------------------------------------------------------
1 NULL ERROR_Melin_ProgressCommon ERROR_Melin_ProgressCommon 2C61C5D9-C712-42C5-B6B9-D355C43C25BB


2 NULL ERROR_Melin_ProgressCommon ERROR_Melin_ProgressCommon 2C61C5D9-C712-42C5-B6B9-D355C43C25BB


3 NULL ERROR_Melin_ProgressCommon ERROR_Melin_ProgressCommon 2C61C5D9-C712-42C5-B6B9-D355C43C25BB

Comment: 1,2 and 3 are unique identifier(Logid) in the table but when i fire scope_identity() it does not return last value 3.It always return null for scope_identity,@@identity and ident_current

Comment: The `OUTPUT` clause can not select into a scalar variable.

Comment: It seems apparent that the id you are trying to select back is NOT an identity. Scope_identity, etc. can only return ids that have been defined as identitiy fields. Please post a table generation script for your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
begin try
    Set XACT_ABORT ON
    BEGIN TRAn
            INSERT into logging.execution_log
                (ParentLogID, Description, PackageName, PackageGuid, MachineName, 
                ExecutionGuid, LogicalDate, Operator, StartTime, EndTime, Status,FailureTask)
            Values(@ParentLogID, @Description, @PackageName, 
                cast(@PackageGuid as uniqueidentifier), @MachineName, 
                cast(@ExecutionGuid as uniqueidentifier),  @logicalDate, 
                @operator, getdate(), null, @status, null)

            Set @LogID = scope_identity()
    Commit Tran
End try

Begin Catch
    Select Error_Message();
    Rollback Tran
End Catch
```

Comment: sorry ,still the same problem.

Comment: this is the data in the table-------------------LogId ParentLogId Description PackageName PackageGuid -------------------------------------------------------------------- 1 NULL ERROR_Melin_ProgressCommon ERROR_Melin_ProgressCommon 2C61C5D9-C712-42C5-‌​B6B9-D355C43C25BB 2 NULL ERROR_Melin_ProgressCommon ERROR_Melin_ProgressCommon 2C61C5D9-C712-42C5-‌​B6B9-D355C43C25BB 3 NULL ERROR_Melin_ProgressCommon ERROR_Melin_ProgressCommon 2C61C5D9-C712-42C5-‌​B6B9-D355C43C25BB –

Comment: sorry As i am new user i can not post picture

Comment: 1,2 and 3 are unique identifier(Logid) in the table but when i fire scope_identity() it does not return last value 3.It always return null for scope_identity,@@identity and ident_current